# How to append a single column from 1 data frame to another data frame based on group

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have 2 data frames (df1,df2) and I would like to append 1 column from df2 to df1 based on a purchasing material number. However, df1 has more rows compared to df2 due to repeats, I would like to keep the repeats and just reassign the value from df2 to the repeat in df1. Here is what I mean

df1:

```
document number: 
111
111
122
133
```

df2:

```
document_number value
133              A
122              B  
111              C
```

what I would like

df3=

```
document_number value
111             C
111             C  
122             B
133             A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do a left join

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   left_join(df2, by = 'document number')
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2,  value := value, on = .(`document number`)]
```

Comment: how about if the  grouping variables have different names in the 2 DF's? also, I do not want to append all the other columns in DF2 ( not OG posted), just the one variable , which is the "value"

Comment: @AJJebelli then you use `c("document number1" = "document number2")`

Comment: how to append just one column? @akrun

Comment: I only want to append the value column from Df2 to DF1, there are other columns in DF2 that I do not want to append to DF1

Comment: @AJJebelli Just subset the columns from "DF2" before joining i.e. `df1 %>% left_join(df1 %>% select(`document number`, value), by = 'document number')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234932/discussion-between-aj-jebelli-and-akrun).